# Regarding classifications of elites

Tags: society, sociology, classification, human

There seem to be two types of elite in general society. There is the elite whose privileges and responsibilities are roughly proportional (such as doctors), and then there are elites whose privileges are dissociated from their responsibilities (such as dictators), making them entitled to far more than what they are responsible for. Are there different terminologies to refer to these two different types of elites?

Comment: Many sociological terms ~ elites, classes etc don't actually have a proper scientific definition. They're basically folk terms. If you tried to categorize different forms of elite there'd be too many variations.